# What's the error with sql instruction?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE VIEW DADOSTORNEIO AS
SELECT TORNEIO.NroTorneio , TORNEIO.NomeTorneio , TORNEIO.DescTorneio , 
    TORNEIO.DataFim , TORNEIO.DataInicio , EQUIPES.CodEquipe , EQUIPES.NomeEquipe , 
    EQUIPES.DescEquipe , ATLETAS.NroAtleta , ATLETAS.NomeAtleta , ATLETAS.TelAtleta , 
    ATLETAS.SexoAtleta , ATLETAS.Modalidade 
FROM TORNEIO , EQUIPES , ATLETAS
WHERE EQUIPES.NroTorneio == TORNEIO.NroTorneio 
  AND ATLETAS.CodEquipe == EQUIPES.CodEquipe 
  AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE()) > TORNEIO.DataFim;
```

The code above submitted the folowing error in Oracle Express 11g:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Which is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3):

Use `=` instead of `==` in the where clause and `SYSDATE` instead of `SYSDATE()`

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the errors pointed out by @RidaBENHAMMANE, `SYSDATE` already is a date - it doesn't make sense to convert it with to_date, so instead of

```
AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE()) > TORNEIO.DataFim;
```

just use

```
AND SYSDATE > TORNEIO.DataFim;
```